# making image go to zero oppacity after certain conditions are met

Tags: if-statement, while-loop, processing, tint

I am using the program processing and stumbled upon a difficulty.
When trying to make an image tint to make it transparent after a certain amount of time, it won't do this, what I have so far :

```
import ddf.minim.*;

Minim minim;
AudioInput in;

PImage img;
int a = 125;//geluidswaarde
int fade = 0;//beginfade grote fade is zwarter
int stmin = 2; //fadestapje donkerder
int stplus = 10; //fadestapje lichter
float gw = 0.04;//gevoeligheid kleiner = gevoeliger
int trmin = 10; // transparanter
int trplus = 20; // voller
int A = 0;

void setup() {
  img = loadImage("leegte.jpg");

  size(1000, 1000);
  frameRate(10); // Maximum 30 frames/beelden per seconde (speel hier gerust even mee)
  image(img, 0, 0);
  minim = new Minim(this); 
  // get a line in from Minim, default bit depth is 16
  in = minim.getLineIn(Minim.STEREO, 640);
}

void draw() {

  image(img, 0, 0);
  fill(255);
  rect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);

  if (abs(in.left.get(a))> (gw)) {
    fade = fade-stplus;
  }
  else {
    fade = fade+stmin;
  }
  fade = constrain(fade, 0, 300);
  fill(0, fade);
  rect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);

  while (fade>=300)
  {
    --A;
    tint(0, A);
  }
}





void stop()



{
  // always close Minim audio classes when you are done with them
  in.close();
  minim.stop();

  super.stop();
}
```

the problem lies in the

```
while (fade>=300)
  {
    --A;
    tint(0, A);
  }
```

part, after the image has reached fade(0,300) I want it to start tinting so it goes from 255 oppacity to 0, however, it just sits there and does nothing afterwards, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're probably ending up with an infinite loop. You tell it too loop as long as `fade` is greater than or equal to `300`. However, you're not modifying `fade` inside the loop, so its value will never change. That means it will never drop below `300`, so the loop will never finish.

Perhaps you meant your loop body to look like this:

```
A = fade;
while (A >= 300)
{
    --A;
    tint(0, A);
}
```

It's also worth noting that the display is only updated **after** any given call to `draw()` has completely finished. That means you won't see any effect from calling `tint()` (or any other drawing functions) repeatedly inside a loop like that. The last call is the only one that will have a visible effect. Instead, you need to decrement and apply `A` each time `draw()` is called.

Lastly, I think `tint()` only affects subsequent images; i.e. it won't affect what's already on the screen. Perhaps you should try setting the tint at the start of `draw()` instead.